# How Service Workers can speed up the store?

Tags: magento2, frontend, pagespeed

It may be useful to introduce service workers to increase loading speed? If yes, which resources are the high priority ones?

Link to Service Workers docs : https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/